# Convert data frame column data types for a set of arbitrarily-named columns

Tags: r, types, mutate

I must combine a set of CSV files into a data frame. On different runs these files will have column names different from those on prior runs. Let's say that on a given run the column names are:

- start_date
- stop_date
- order_num
- rate
- amount

By examining the column names and using domain knowledge I can determine that the data types for these columns in the data frame I'm creating should be:

- start_date - date
- stop_date  - date
- order_num  - character
- rate       - currency
- amount     - integer

Until the requirement changed from a fixed set of column names to an arbitrary set I used a function employing mutate_at() to set the data types of the columns. The drawback with that approach is that when a different set of columns (with their associated data types) is supplied, I must manually edit that function.

Suppose I took that list of column names and created a tibble like this:

```
columns <- tribble(
  ~.colname, ~.datatype,
  "start_date", "date",
  "stop_date", "date",
  "order_num", "character",
  "rate", "currency",
  "amount", "integer"
)
```

and using that same set of column names I have a tibble like this:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~.start_date, ~.stop_date, ~.order_num, ~.rate, ~.amount,
  "2023-06-01", "2023-06-30", "52471", "1.25", "20"
)
```

What technique can I use to assign the data types to the df tibble using the values in the columns$.datatype column?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `readr` to accomplish this.

First note that there is no type `currency` in R. For now we will change that to numeric/double:

```
columns[4,2] <-'numeric'
```

Then we have to ensure that the names match, ie by adding the `.` at the begining of the names of the dataframe to the names given in the columns dataframe:

```
columns1 <- mutate(columns, .colname = str_c('.', .colname))
```

Now we could do:

```
library(tidyverse)

type_convert(df, cols(!!!deframe(columns1)))
 
# A tibble: 1 × 5
  .start_date .stop_date .order_num .rate .amount
  <date>      <date>     <chr>      <dbl>   <int>
1 2023-06-01  2023-06-30 52471       1.25      20
```

---

A base R approach:

```
a <- c(toString(names(df)), do.call(paste, c(df, sep = ',')))
b <- with(columns, setNames(.datatype, paste0('.', .colname)))
read.csv(text = a, colClasses = sub('date', 'Date', b))

.start_date .stop_date .order_num .rate .amount
1  2023-06-01 2023-06-30      52471  1.25      20
```

You can easily check whether it worked by using the `str` function:

```
str(read.csv(text = a, colClasses = sub('date', 'Date', b)))
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ .start_date: Date, format: "2023-06-01"
 $ .stop_date : Date, format: "2023-06-30"
 $ .order_num : chr "52471"
 $ .rate      : num 1.25
 $ .amount    : int 20
```

Comment: *.order_num* should be "character"

Comment: @AndreWildberg you are right. Just noticed the namings were different. Added that in and now the code works

Answer (score 0):

A rather long-winded approach using `parse` and `eval`.

Also changing `columns$.datatype` "date" to "Date" and "currency" to "numeric".

```
library(dplyr)

columns$.datatype <- c("Date", "Date", "character", "numeric", "integer")

setNames(lapply(sub("^\\.", "", colnames(df)), function(x)
  eval(parse(text = 
    paste0("as.", columns$.datatype[grep(x, columns$.colname)], 
           "(df$.", x, ")")))), colnames(df)) %>% 
  as_tibble()
# A tibble: 1 × 5
  .start_date .stop_date .order_num .rate .amount
  <date>      <date>     <chr>      <dbl>   <int>
1 2023-06-01  2023-06-30 52471       1.25      20
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R Solution:

```
# Function to coerce vectors in a data.frame to types given in 
# a schema: coerce_types => function
coerce_types <- function(
  df1, 
  schema_column_names, 
  schema_data_types, 
  numeric_types = c("integer", "currency", "numeric", "float", "double", "decimal"),
  logical_types = c("bit", "boolean", "bool", "logical")
){
  # Break if df1 is not a data.frame: 
  stopifnot(is.data.frame(df1))
  # Resolve the column names of the data.frame: 
  # nms => character vector
  nms <- colnames(df1)
  # Break if column names aren't strings: 
  stopifnot(is.character(schema_column_names))
  # Break if data types is not a character vector: 
  stopifnot(is.character(schema_data_types))
  # Break if the numeric types and logical type param args aren't 
  # character vectors: 
  stopifnot(is.character(numeric_types) & is.character(logical_types))
  # Break if there are no columns that match between the schema column 
  # names and data.frame
  stopifnot(any(schema_column_names %in% nms))
  # Ensure the Data Types are lower case: 
  # lower_data_types => character vector
  lower_data_types <- trimws(tolower(schema_data_types))
  # Resolve where the column names are in the schema data.frame: 
  # idx => integer vector
  idx <- na.omit(match(nms, schema_column_names))
  # Sort the data frame by the columns: df2 => data.frame
  df2 <- df1[,idx]
  # Coerce the data types: df1 => data.frame 
  df2[] <- lapply(
    idx,
    function(i){
      schema_col_name <- schema_column_names[i]
      data_type <- lower_data_types[i]
      if(data_type == "date"){
        as.Date(df2[,i,drop = TRUE])
      }else if(data_type %in% trimws(tolower(numeric_types))){
        as.numeric(df2[,i,drop = TRUE])
      }else if(data_type %in% trimws(tolower(logical_types))){
        as.logical(df2[,i,drop = TRUE])
      }else{
        as.character(df2[,i,drop = TRUE])
      }
    }
  )
  # Explicitly define the returned object, with the correct column order 
  # data.frame => env
  return(df2[,nms,drop = FALSE])
}
## Function Application & Testing
# Test for case where no columns are present in data.frame 
# defined in schema data.frame: 
coerce_types(df1, c("hello", "friend"), c("character", "string"))
# Drop starting period from names: df2 => data.frame
df1 <- setNames(
  df, 
  gsub(
    "^\\.(.*)$", 
    "\\1", 
    colnames(df)
  )
)
# Test on cleaned column name data.frame: 
# data.frame => stdout(console)
coerce_types(df1, columns$.colname, columns$.datatype)
# Reverse the order of the columns: 
# df2 => data.frame
df2 <- df1[,rev(colnames(df1))]
# Test on reversed cleaned column name data.frame: 
# data.frame => stdout(console)
coerce_types(df2, columns$.colname, columns$.datatype)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help. I've been reading through your answers and working alternate solutions and have developed one I'm comfortable with.

```
    library(tidyverse)


# Starting with a list of column names supplied by the customer: 
# start_date, stop_date, order_num, rate, amount
# I create a two-column tab-separated text file using
# domain knowledge to identify the desired data types
# for each column.
# I read in the text file to a data frame.

t <- read.table("data/col_list.txt", header = TRUE)

# I now create an empty data frame
# which will hold the data supplied by the customer
# and will modify the column data types per
# the "t" data frame.

df <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=0, ncol = nrow(t))) 
colnames(df) <- t$columns_names
 
# I found it convenient to create a function to transform
# the column data types. Using this function will make for
# easier debugging and easier for maintenance programmers
# to follow the logic.

fetch_column_names_by_data_type <- function(df, datatype){
  subset(df, data_types == datatype) %>% 
    select(columns_names) %>% 
    unname() %>% 
    unlist()
}

# Transform the column data types

date_columns <- fetch_column_names_by_data_type(t, "as.Date")
numeric_columns <- fetch_column_names_by_data_type(t, "as.numeric")
character_columns <- fetch_column_names_by_data_type(t, "as.character")
integer_columns <- fetch_column_names_by_data_type(t, "as.integer")

df <- df %>% mutate_at(date_columns, as.Date) %>% 
             mutate_at(numeric_columns, as.numeric) %>% 
             mutate_at(character_columns, as.character) %>% 
             mutate_at(integer_columns, as.integer)

str(df)
```